# how am I breaking rules of hook?

Tags: react-native

```
export default function PreferVar(){
const [prefer,setPrefer]=useState({})
useEffect(()=>{
fire.database().ref().child('/users/preference').once("value",(snapshot)=>{
    const item=snapshot.val()
    setPrefer(item)
  }
  );},[])
return(prefer)
}
```

error message
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. 
where am I and Which rule am I breaking exactly?

Comment: Hooks may only be called in functional components or another hook (which is what you appear to be trying to do here), which needs to follow the standard naming convention for hooks. If you rename your function `usePreferVar` it will probably stop complaining. Also, `return` is not a function.

Comment: what is preferVar ?

Comment: I am still getting same error

Comment: @rajithShetty you shouldn't be. How are you calling your custom hook?

Comment: `import PreferVar from '../profile/preferVar';

export default class personalFoodCard extends React.Component{
    prefVar=PreferVar()
     getPref=()=>{ `

Comment: @rajithShetty that's your problem. You can't call hooks in a class component, they are for pure functional components. Either stick to classes and use the lifecycle methods, or use pure functional components and hooks.

Comment: ok I'll change my code and see if it works

Comment: yes thankyou very much.How do i close the question